# Can I prevent the Firefox developer tools network panel from clearing on page reload?

Tags: http, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to observe the contents of a POST request whose successful completion results in a `location.reload()` - when I try to capture this request in the Network Panel of the Firefox developer tools, I find that the page reload clears the list of captured events. Can I prevent this clearing?

Comment: How about accepting vossad01 answer ?

Comment: ...or the other one, doesn't really matter. Accept you should, though.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

From Firefox 31 onwards you can use the ["**Enable persistent logs**" setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings) to prevent the Network Monitor from clearing the list on reload.

Comment: And it's on central column on the top of the screen  (for those who haven't an english version of the settings, in fr : "Préférence générales/activer les journaux persistants")

Comment: I wonder how could they possibly do such a bad job cloning firebug. Which is all they really needed to do. Those guys must be blind or something.

Answer (score 93):

Despite knowing the name for the setting is "Enable persistent logs", it took me a while to find it on the settings page.  I hope this helps:

[image: Location of "Enable persistent logs" setting in Firefox]

Answer (score 53):

Roughly three years after [BeetleJuice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3977061/beetlejuice)'s [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524848/1529709), it seems to have moved again - now, you need to click the gear icon on the far right side for the option  to appear. Hooray for our ever-changing user interface soup.

[image]

Comment: Hooray - that's the solution for Firefox 93

Comment: NB This is with the network tab selected.

Answer (score 39):

I couldn't find this setting in Firefox 57. The setting has been moved to the network tab itself, above the log table

[image]

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, this is how you do it in Chrome DevTools as well, the checkbox is along the top bar in the Network tab.

Answer (score 11):

If "Enable persistent Log" settings is not available in the devtool settings, you can go to `about:config`(type this in the URL box and enter) page and search for `persistlog` and change it from there(toggle button on the right).

I can see two options and enabled both. :)

`devtools.netmonitor.persistlog`, `devtools.webconsole.persistlog`

Comment: This is the right answer for Firefox in MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can find it when click on the gear under the tab network

[image: firefox tab network]