# Prevent Firefox from clearing network log on reload: missing pref

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm observing network requests made in Firefox 57 64bit. I'd like to stop the browser from clearing the network log when a page loads.

The same question [was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41593720/3977061) but I do not have the "*enable persistent logs*" option in my devtool settings:

[image]

Is there some other way to solve my problem, or is there a way to make the "*enable persistent logs*" setting appear in my UI?

Answer (score 1):

This setting has been moved. On Firefox 57, it is a checkbox on the Network tab itself, above the log table

[image]